# Keras --- About Masking Layer followed by a Reshape Layer

Tags: deep-learning, keras, reshape, lstm

I want to using mask before LSTM, but the output of Lstm must be reshape to 4 dim.
So my code:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(96,1000), name='main_input')

pre_input = BatchNormalization()(main_input)

aaa= Masking(mask_value=0)(pre_input)

recurrent1 = LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)(aaa)

r_out= Reshape((1,96,256))(recurrent1)`
```

But it runs with error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d1107015501b> in <module>()
     17 recurrent1 = LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)(aaa)
     18 
---> 19 r_out= Reshape((1,96,256))(recurrent1)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __call__(self, x, mask)
    512         if inbound_layers:
    513             # this will call layer.build() if necessary
--> 514             self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    515             input_added = True
    516 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in add_inbound_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    570         # creating the node automatically updates self.inbound_nodes
    571         # as well as outbound_nodes on inbound layers.
--> 572         Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    573 
    574     def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in create_node(cls, outbound_layer, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
    148         if len(input_tensors) == 1:
    149             output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
--> 150             output_masks = to_list(outbound_layer.compute_mask(input_tensors[0], input_masks[0]))
    151             # TODO: try to auto-infer shape if exception is raised by get_output_shape_for
    152             output_shapes = to_list(outbound_layer.get_output_shape_for(input_shapes[0]))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in compute_mask(self, input, input_mask)
    605                 else:
    606                     raise Exception('Layer ' + self.name + ' does not support masking, ' +
--> 607                                     'but was passed an input_mask: ' + str(input_mask))
    608             # masking not explicitly supported: return None as mask
    609             return None

Exception: Layer reshape_1 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Any{2}.0
```

I have print out, the outshape of recurrent1 is (96,256)

How could I make it right?

Comment: please paste you actual console output formatted as code and do not post a screenshot of your console

Comment: I meant editing your question to replace the console output

Comment: ok, i edited my question